# Detect last item of an Iterator

Tags: rust

My code analyzes log files line by line. The last line typically is an empty ("") line and should be ignored completely. But how can I detect the last line in my loop?
The iterator doesn't know how long it is and collecting all items to an array is inefficient and might fill up memory too much.

```rust
let file = File::open(&files[index])
    .map_err(|e| format!("Could not open log file: {}", e))?;
let reader = BufReader::new(file);
for (index, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
    let line = line.unwrap();
    if is_last_line() && line == "" {
        break;
    }
    // do something with the line...
}
```

`is_last_line()` doesn't exist. How to detect the last line?

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [`Itertools::with_position`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.with_position) function:

```
use itertools::{Itertools, Position};

let file = File::open(&files[index]).map_err(|e| format!("Could not open log file: {}", e))?;
let reader = BufReader::new(file);

for line in reader.lines().enumerate().with_position() {
    match line {
        Position::Last((idx, _)) => println!("line {} is the last line!", idx),
        Position::First((idx, text)) | Position::Middle((idx, text)) => (),
        Position::Only((idx, _)) => println!("there is only one line in your file"),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable) adapter.

This requires switching to manual iteration (a `while let` loop and explicitly calling `next`), but it lets you `peek()` the iterator to see if there is a next item. If there isn't, you know it's the last line (at least for the more fusable iterators).

```rust
let file = File::open(&files[index])
    .map_err(|e| format!("Could not open log file: {}", e))?;
let reader = BufReader::new(file);
let mut iterator = reader.lines().enumerate().peekable();
while let Some((index, line)) = iterator.next() {
    if line == "" && iterator.peek().is_none() {
        break;
    }
    // do something with the line...
}
```

Comment: peakable is interesting but it workes a bit different here: `while let Some((line_index, Ok(line))) = iterator.next()`. And it seems to drop the last empty line be default without the if condition. I tested it with different file endings. An empty line is dropped, empty middle lines not, and a ending line with content is not dropped.

Comment: Just realized with this while loop, I don't even need peekable(). It works with enumerate() too. My sample code was not complete. Before I had to unwrap line. Now this is not needed anymore and the loop stops when last line is empty.